# Create faux dyndns using php and htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, owncloud, dyndns

I'm trying to set up an owncloud instance, and trying to pass it through owncloud.[mydomain].com, running the owncloud from a home server but passing through a domain I get through a hosting provider.

The problem is, my hosting provider doesn't support dynamic dns, and I've tried asking them if they have any way or will.

I've seen that, using htaccess, php can sometimes mimic dns redirects. Is there a way to do so dynamically so that ddclient on a linux system can update it?

Comment: Not sure if the adverse effects of htaccess DNS forwarding are bad but before trying have you considered making an A record to the DNS to point the domain to owncloud? I’m thinking there must be a way to do it via DNS entry on the domain level, otherwise you can just forward via htaccess on the root directory of your site but it won’t be native as it would be pointing the DNS/namespace, surely there must be a way you could explore via the domains DNS records to point it to your machine

Comment: Looks like someone’s done it with a CNAME record on the domain DNS; https://www.madewithtea.com/simple-way-of-hosting-your-owncloud.html worth the read

Comment: @IlanP Sadly, the link you shared, although useful for some instances, doesn't work for me. The example there, the owncloud is setup on the digitalocean servers, which have a reliable name server. The home server I"m setting up my owncloud on will be an often-changing address from my hosting provider.

Comment: Ah sorry, with htaccess you can redirect but it’ll only be as efficient as a domain forward, I doubt it’s what you really need; you’d be better off transferring to a provider that’ll support your needs imo; I get you have a dynamic addy you need a way to point to it when it changes but unless you can opt for dynamic dns support for the domain I think you’ll end up with a forward technique you may need want (just an opinion) wish the link was of use tho